# What skill sets are required to develop a plugin for safari, firefox, chrome and IE using NPAPI or Firebreath

Tags: npapi, firebreath

What skill sets are required to develop a plugin for safari, firefox, chrome and IE using NPAPI or Firebreath? Noob here so please go easy on me...

Answer (score 5):

The main skills I can think of would be:

- C and C++
- Having made browser plugins before, if possible (there's not much that will translate directly other than having actually done it before)
- Experience with software development on as many of the platforms you are going to support as possible. Especially useful would be experience with the drawing primitives of each, since NPAPI has no drawing abstraction across platforms.
- Knowing how to read other people's code (since that's going to be the best place to learn the details of how plugins work)
- Being able to sift through lots of different incomplete and/or obsolete documentation sources.

One correction: you can't write an IE plugin using NPAPI. You have to use ActiveX, or an abstraction like Firebreath.

Comment: Probably helpful to be at least competent in javascript (to test, to demonstrate, and to understand what's going on).  If you use FireBreath (which I recommend) you'll end up wading into CMake (urg).  If you want to code-sign your plugin, be prepared to learn way more than you ever wanted to know about that, including certificates and chains of trust.
And... "sift through lots of different incomplete and/or obsolete documentation sources" - amen to that.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to learn more than one ever wanted to learn. I've found that videos are a good way to learn these days and if I don't find a good one I think I'll give it a shot. I need to learn it anyways.